# Problem in registering a 32 bit C++ COM/ATL Service on Windows7 64 bit

Tags: visual-c++, com, windows-services, 64-bit, atl

My product have a **ATL/COM based C++ service (32 bit)**. It get registered and run fine on XP 32 bit and Vista 32 bit.

But now I want to run the same **on Windows7 64 bit also**. I tried to register the service the following way:

1 I did Copy MyService.exe at C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

2 Then executing **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MyService.exe" -RegServer** from Start->Run

3 Then executing **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MyService.exe" -Service** from Start->Run

But my service is not getting registered. While registering it, I don't get any error message. Also I didn't find any entry in event viewer (I saw event viewer first time. Don't know where to see the log about registration of my service). And I didn't find entry for my service at **Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Services**.

Please advise me how can I register my service?

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Comment: Have you tried Process Monitor?

Comment: you should accept his answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

If UAC is enabled on the machine then registering it via Start -> Run is unlikely to work as it would almost certainly need full administrator rights to register its objects and create its service.

Open an Administrator command prompt and try registering it from there.

(Find Command Prompt in the start menu, right-click it and select Run as Administrator.)

Alternatively, instead of using Start -> Run, type the command directly into the Windows 7 start menu and then push Ctrl-Shift-Return to run it as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks Friend. I have really been stupid for not doing that. It really works. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the keyboard shortcut tip.  I have never heard of that and will definitely use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try commands at cmd running at administrator rights.